# how can I use sass color functions in js

Tags: javascript, sass

How can I use sass color-functions like `change-color`, `darkness`, `lightness` etc within JS code to manipulate colors?

Actually I want to build a JS library for my app to which I will give a color and then perform operations like sass `change-color` etc on it.

For example I want to build something like:

```js
function changeColor(color, options){ 
  // calling sass change-color functionality so that it will 
  // return color and I can perform my application specific logic 
}
```

------------- EDITED ----------

I am using `ruby sass`.

Comment: This will help you https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color

Comment: @Gimnath sorry for not mentioning in the question but I am using `ruby sass`.

Comment: moreover I am talking about using sass color functions like functions on JS so I can manipulate colors

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this prolem. I could not find the source code behind those functions or a library exposing them.

What I did find was [this blog entry](https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2020/sass-color-functions-in-css/), that builds every function with CSS, which is great as you can see what is behind each of them.

The blog introduces them like this:

> Sass has the following functions, each of which essentially takes a color, puts it in the HSL color space, then adds/subtracts the value as defined by the developer.